# Accessing a property of an object using AppleScript

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, sdef

I'm adding AppleScript support to my macOS application but I have problems accessing a property of an object I defined.

The sdef file resulted in the following directory:

[image: sdef activities]

When I run the following script:

```
tell application "Daily"
    get all activities
end tell
```

I get this result:

[image: get all activities output]

However, when I run this script:

```
tell application "Daily"
    repeat with iActivity in (get all activities)
        name of iActivity
    end repeat
end tell
```

I get this error:

```
error "Daily got an error: Can’t make «class » id \"E10E6A7B-6D3B-464B-9C31-35DB6763C492\" into type specifier." number -1700 from «class » id "E10E6A7B-6D3B-464B-9C31-35DB6763C492" to specifier
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: In your application "Daily", what class is it "meant" to return? eg. (NSString, etc...)

Comment: Don't put command "get all activities" in the dictionary. Applescript can do this.

Comment: Thanks Willeke. However, "get all activities" will be replaced into something like "get all activities between <date> and <date>". These dates are not part of the model and I assume filtering will be hard because of this.